# How to properly remove sensiolabs/security-checker from my symfony 4.4 LTS project

Tags: symfony, composer-php

I have a Symfony 4.4 codebase, where I need to remove the now deprecated security checker package.
But to simple run `composer remove sensiolabs/security-checker` does not properly remove the package.

```
composer remove sensiolabs/security-checker

./composer.json has been updated
Running composer update sensiolabs/security-checker
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies
Lock file operations: 0 installs, 0 updates, 2 removals
  - Removing composer/ca-bundle (1.2.9)
  - Removing sensiolabs/security-checker (v5.0.3)
Writing lock file
Installing dependencies from lock file (including require-dev)
Package operations: 0 installs, 0 updates, 2 removals
  - Removing sensiolabs/security-checker (v5.0.3)
  - Removing composer/ca-bundle (1.2.9)
Generating autoload files
composer/package-versions-deprecated: Generating version class...
composer/package-versions-deprecated: ...done generating version class
84 packages you are using are looking for funding.
Use the `composer fund` command to find out more!

Symfony operations: 2 recipes (acd31206aa63ca25126df4f0b5f09748)
  - Unconfiguring sensiolabs/security-checker (>=4.0): From github.com/symfony/recipes:master
  - Unconfiguring composer/ca-bundle (>=1.2.9): From auto-generated recipe
Synchronizing package.json with PHP packages
Don't forget to run npm install --force or yarn install --force to refresh your JavaScript dependencies!
Executing script cache:clear [KO]
 [KO]
Script cache:clear returned with error code 1
!!
!!  In AddConsoleCommandPass.php line 53:
!!
!!    Class "SensioLabs\Security\Command\SecurityCheckerCommand" used for service
!!     "SensioLabs\Security\Command\SecurityCheckerCommand" cannot be found.
!!
!!
!!
Script @auto-scripts was called via post-update-cmd
```

I cleared (and removed) the cache, and I also reset (removed and reinstalled) the vendors once.

But I always get the SensioLabs\Security\Command\SecurityCheckerCommand not found error.

It seems as some parts remains which is called by the `composer.json` @auto-scripts entry?

This is the `composer.json`

```
{
    "type": "project",
    "license": "proprietary",
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.1.3",
        "ext-ctype": "*",
        "ext-iconv": "*",
        "ext-json": "*",
        "ext-mbstring": "*",
        "ext-bcmath": "*",
        "ext-simplexml": "*",
        "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "^5.2",
        "symfony/asset": "*",
        "symfony/console": "*",
        "symfony/expression-language": "*",
        "symfony/finder": "*",
        "symfony/flex": "^1.2",
        "symfony/form": "*",
        "symfony/framework-bundle": "*",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "^3.1",
        "symfony/orm-pack": "*",
        "symfony/security-bundle": "*",
        "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "^3.2",
        "symfony/templating": "*",
        "symfony/translation": "*",
        "symfony/twig-bundle": "*",
        "symfony/validator": "*",
        "symfony/webpack-encore-bundle": "^1.6",
        "symfony/yaml": "*"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle": "^3.0",
        "symfony/debug-pack": "*",
        "symfony/dotenv": "*",
        "symfony/phpunit-bridge": "*",
        "symfony/profiler-pack": "^1.0"
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": {
            "*": "dist"
        },
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "src/App/",
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\Tests\\": "tests/App/"
        }
    },
    "replace": {
        "symfony/polyfill-ctype": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-iconv": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php71": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php70": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php56": "*"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "auto-scripts": {
            "cache:clear": "symfony-cmd",
            "assets:install %PUBLIC_DIR%": "symfony-cmd"
        },
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "@auto-scripts"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "@auto-scripts"
        ]
    },
    "conflict": {
        "symfony/symfony": "*"
    },
    "extra": {
        "symfony": {
            "allow-contrib": false,
            "require": "4.4.*"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Remove security_checker.yaml from your config files

Comment: I needed to remove config/security_checker.yaml AND the config/dev/security_checker.yaml.
(I always forgot to check the config subfolders!)
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You need to remove it also from the composer.json `"auto-scripts"` section, you probably have something like this:

```
"auto-scripts": {
    ...
    "security-checker security:check": "script"
},
```

Comment: Unfortunately no, I searched everywhere for the security-checker.